# Proof involving the difference of iid normal random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to prove that, for two i.i.d. random variables $X_1,X_2 \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, their difference divided by $\sqrt  2$ is standard normal, i.e. $\frac {X_1-X_2}{\sqrt 2} \sim N(0,1)$.

I am trying to show it using convolution, but am getting caught up in the algebra of trying to get it into a recognizable form. I think there is a more simple way using the definition of expectation, but when I try it, it doesn't quite come out right as I get $N(0, \sigma^2)$ instead of $N(0,1)$.

Comment: @angryavian So the problem I am having with the linear combination approach comes down to the variance. I am trying to calculate as follows:

Var[(X_1-X_2)/sqrt(2)]=(1/2)Var[X_1-X_2]=2(1/2)Var[X_1]=sigma^2

So I'm getting sigma^2 instead of 1. Can you help me find my mistake?

Comment: It's not a mistake. You need to divide by $\sqrt{2}\sigma$ to get $N(0,1)$.

Comment: The simplest way to prove this is to use characteristic functions. Are you allowed to do that?. (As already pointed out you will not get $N(0,1)$ if you divide by $\sqrt 2$).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I'm allowed to do anything. This is not for a homework or school assignment, I'm just reading my way through a textbook and came upon an something that I couldn't immediately see how to prove. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Ee^{itX_1}=e^{it\mu}e^{-t^{2}\sigma^{2}/2}$. Hence $Ee^{it(X_1-X_2)/\sqrt2 \sigma)}=Ee^{itX_1/\sqrt2 \sigma)}Ee^{-itX_2/\sqrt2 \sigma)}=(e^{-t^{2}/4})^{2}=e^{-t^{2}/2}$ which is the characteristic function of $N(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks so much Kavi! I see how this works when we have that factor of $\sigma$ in the denominator. Unfortunately, the book I have just has $\frac{X_1-X_2}{\sqrt{2}}$ :(. Maybe it's an error, but there is an important proof that seems to rest on it, so that is rather discouraging.